# How does google manage sso through multiple domain [google.com, youtube.com]

Tags: javascript, https, single-sign-on, session-cookies, setcookie

When we log in google. It set cookies for both Google and youtube domain.
In the network, I see two interesting get call,

1. https://mail.google.com/accounts/SetOSID?authuser
2. https://accounts.youtube.com/accounts/SetSID.

How can I achieve the same results?

I have to set a cookie for a website like youtube.com from a website like google.com.

I tried making a XMLHttpRequest(). It didn't work. But If I open my second domain in a separate tab, It set the cookie for the second domain.

```
My request header :
Request URL: https://mysite.ngrok.io/SetSID?params=xyz
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 302 Found
Remote Address: xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxx
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade


My Response Header :
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Length: 184
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 09 May 2018 16:29:34 GMT
Location: https://mysite.ngrok.io/SetSID/callback?params=xyz
set-cookie: _cookie=sample; Path=/; HttpOnly
Vary: Accept
X-Powered-By: Express
```

If we inspect the console, the request type is binary.

Did it somehow help them achieve the current goal ?

[image]

1. This API is hit
   https://myaccount.google.com/accounts/SetOSID?authuser=1&continue=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.youtube.com%2Faccounts%2FSetSID
2. followed by the api
       https://accounts.youtube.com/accounts/SetSID?ssdc=1&sidt=xxx&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/u//?authuser

If I am not wrong, Google is loading the https://accounts.youtube.com in a split second and setting up the cookies. It then continue to mail.google.com. (see the params in continue)